# call a php page using cron jobs in direct admin

Tags: php, cron

I have a php file that sends an email and it works fine when I open the page with browser. (test.php located in root of my website) But I want the page runs automatically once a day. I found that this is done using cron jobs. I searched a lot and tested a lot of commands and configurations but none of them worked.
I was using * for all time fields assuming that it will run every minute (I didn't like to wait hours to test each configuration)
I tested following commands and many others that I don't remember ):

```
/usr/bin/php -q http://mysite.com/test.php
/usr/bin/home/php -q http://mysite.com/test.php
/usr/local/bin/php -q http://mysite.com/test.php
/home/myID/php -q http://mysite.com/test.php
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q http://mysite.com/test.php
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/myID/mysite.com/public_html/test.php
```

Finally, I couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.
the host is a shared linux host running Direct Admin.

Please tell me a simple step by step guide to set the cron job to run my php file.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to call the PHP binary if you're going to run the script via http. You want to use wget (or curl). Example:

```
*/5 * * * * user /usr/bin/wget http://yoursite.com/cron.html -q -O /dev/null
```

Where user is the OS user that runs the command.

If you don't have the privileges (shared host) to do something like that, change to use a VPS instance from some provider or use an online cronjob service like https://www.setcronjob.com/.

Comment: well, you have to find out how this is done on your server, don't just copy paste what I wrote her, it's only an example. Where's your wget binary? Don't use the -q option and run it manually in the shell to see what happens.

Comment: unfortunately my hosting company doesn't provide enough information about the location of binaries. I contacted them but they don't have information about this issue. I wonder if there is a way to find it myself, for example from phpInfo() information. Additionally DirectAdmin does not accept *s in command line. I have to enter them in text boxes. Maybe this also helps "/home/myUserID/" is already written in command box of cron job being added.

Comment: If you're on a shared host, don't do this. Either change to a VPS hosting where you have root or use a cron service like https://www.setcronjob.com/.

Comment: I think I should use a service like you said. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the page using lynx the command line browser:

```
lynx -dump http://www.google.com/ > /dev/null
```

Or use a service like http://cronless.com

**Update:**
If you setup a cron job in your control panel and it didn't run then most probably your web host disabled it.

My advice is to use a cron job service like cronless.

Comment: cronless.com works fine but I want to use the capabilities of my own hosting.

Comment: Could you let me know what happens when you execute the command?

Comment: There is a cron jobs page in control panel of my hosting (DirectAdmin). I set time values then enter the command and then add cron job to the list by clicking add button. Then, nothing happens... I wait and the script doesn't run at all because I don't get any emails.